# Python 2.7 Output from text files without last blank line

Tags: python

I've started to learn Python and I stucked on one task - I have 10 text files and I am trying to write from them two outputs:
Output 1 should look like
folder and name of file               header
folder and name of file               header
...

Output 2 should look like
folder and name of file | text | text | text
folder and name of file | text | text | text
...

Although I looked throught many of questions, I have not found, how to delete (or not write) last blank row - there should be always only text.
All solutions I tried (tell(), rstrip(), ...) deleted all signs for new line, so I had file like 
folder and name of file               headerfolder and name of file               header.
Ufortunatelly because of the task definition I am allowed to use only glob and re, so helpful sys is forbidden for me :(

I would really appreciate your help with that, this task is for me really challenging but now I do not know how to continue :)

Thanks for any advice and have a nice day ;)

Code I am using:

```
    import re, glob
    file_list = glob.glob('./input/*txt')
    for file_name in file_list:
    input_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    output_1 = open('file_1', 'a')
    output_2 = open('file_2', 'a')
    for line in input_file:
    if re.search(r'\s{2,}\S{4,}\s{1}\S+:.*', line):
                    output_2.write(file_name.replace('.txt','|') + line)
            if re.search(r'\s{3,}\S{3,16}\s+X?\s[A-Z]{3,4}\d?\s+\d{1,3}.*', line):
                    field = re.findall('\S{3,16}\s{3,}', line) + re.findall('\s{2}\d{1,3}.*', line)
                    field_join = '|'.join(field)
                    field_clear = re.sub(r'(\s){2,}', '', field_join)
                    field_list = re.sub(' ', '|', field_clear, 1)
                    output_1.write(file_name.replace('.txt','|') + field_list + '\n')
    output_2.close()
    output_1.close()
    input_file.close()
```

Comment: You said rstrip doesn't work? Do you save the result in a variable? It's not an in place function.

Comment: @ollien - yep, I tried, unfortunatelly without success

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the loop just `continue` (immediately go to next loop iteration without executing any more code) if it's a blank line:

```
for line in input_file:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    # etc
```

EDIT: For only the last line if it's blank:

```
input_file = input_file.readlines()
last_iter = len(input_file) - 1
for idx, line in enumerate(input_file):
    if idx == last_iter and not line.strip():
        break
```

Or before the loop:

```
input_file = input_file.readlines()
if not input_file[-1].strip():
    input_file = input_file[:-1]
```

Comment: The question was to only eliminate the **last** line, not every blank line

Comment: @GRX'mike Thank you very much :) However, I tried both solution and I still have last line blank (it is written as new line from the last result)...